# Is there any officially recommended way to store passwords?

Tags: .net

Is there any officially recommended way to store passwords?

UPD It's not about server, it's about desktop. I do need to store the password to access remote web service. No hashes ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows [DPAPI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms995355.aspx) is the way to go.

This is encapsulated in .net by the [System.Security.Cryptography.ProtectedData](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.protecteddata.aspx) class (this link contains a basic sample)

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the recommended way is to never store actual passwords but only their [hashes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function). For increased security you could hash them with a [salt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_%28cryptography%29) and store the salt as well. Here's an [article](http://www.aspheute.com/english/20040105.asp) you may find useful.

Comment: ...and not just any hashes, either.

Comment: Since you mentioned salt you might want to be more specific about where to store it.

Comment: @jgauffin, that's explained in the article I've linked to, suffice to read it.

Comment: mkay. Just me being lazy then. +1

Answer (score 2):

You should store hashes of the passwords using [bcrypt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bcrypt).

Answer (score 1):

Hashes are the usual answer, [except if you live in France](http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/technology-12983734), apparently.
Under french law, web sites must store a copy of their users' data (including their passwords) and hand them over to the authorities if requested.
This would force web sites to store full passwords in a retrievable form (and not just their hashes) and is being challenged in court by Google, eBay and others.

Answer (score 0):

The way that Microsoft does in the Membership service, serving the User management facilities.

Hashing the passwords with SHA1 (AFAIR) and saving them.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479048.aspx#bucupro_topic11

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa478949.aspx

Comment: But I thought that the MD5 is outdated not SHA1 cause it has a very lo collision rate. and the strength of encryption depends on many parameters like the size of key and double encryption & ..

Comment: They're both outdated; SHA512 is current.  However, don't use it.  http://chargen.matasano.com/chargen/2007/9/7/enough-with-the-rainbow-tables-what-you-need-to-know-about-s.html